# Can I type an object in such a way to allow only its keys as its value?

Tags: typescript

Simplified problem: let's say we have a graph and that each node has its unique name. If we were to have a type that describes graph edges as a map from name to list of node names you could come to from that node, how would we do that?

Logically, that would be something like:

```
type EdgesT = { [name: string]: Exclude<keyof EdgesT, name>[]; };
```

But I just can't get that description working, even without exclude part, as it always sees keyof EdgesT as string.

Alternatively, if the same problem was for a function argument, we could do something like:

```
type BuildEdges<T> = { [Name in keyof T]: Exclude<keyof T, Name>[]; };

const fn = <T>(edges: BuildEdges<T>) => null;
```

And that works, for that explicit case. But if we were to get more info out of type argument (for something else), we couldn't. For type argument, `<T>` works, `<T extends Record<string, any>>` works, `<T extends Record<string, unknown>>` works, but anything else does not. For example, `<T extends Record<string, number>>` does not work - does anyone has any idea why?

Any idea about working around this situation, achieving a bit more, or describing this limitation?

Comment: How about `T extends BuildEdges<T>` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wR1d5W)?  I'm not sure exactly which piece of your text is "the" question. There is no specific type in TypeScript that works the way you want; it needs to be generic, and thus the best you can do is a helper function like `fn`. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure how to accept this answer, but you DID ANSWER my question. I couldn't think of that type of recursive typing. Thank you very much - you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Well, it's not an answer yet, just a comment asking if it's what you need. I'll write up an actual answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way. It is fundamentally [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). You can't represent it as a large [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `BuildEdges<T>` for every possible `T`.  Conceptually it would be a special kind of generic type called an *[existentially quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) generic*... you want to say "a value is a `BuildEges` if there *exists* some `T` that works". But TypeScript doesn't directly support existential types (although there is an open feature request for them as [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#)). In an alternate universe where that was implemented, maybe you could write

```
// THIS IS NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT, DO NOT TRY:
type BuildEdges = <exists T>{ [K in keyof T]: Exclude<keyof T, K> []; }
```

But for now you need to do something else.

---

There are ways to encode existential types in TypeScript, but they end up being more complicated than I think you need here.  Instead, you could just leave it as a regular generic type like

```
type BuildEdges<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<keyof T, K>[]; };
```

And then write a helper function to infer `T` given the value.  This was your approach anyway, but it seems you didn't find a good [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Here's how I'd do it:

```
const fn = <T extends BuildEdges<T>>(edges: T) => null;
```

That's a recursive constraint. It essentially validates that `T` is a proper `BuildEdges<T>`, leading to the following desirable behavior:

```
fn({ a: ["c"], b: ["a"], c: ["a", "b"] }); // okay
fn({ a: ["c"], b: ["a"], c: ["a", "c"] }); // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/PQKgUALgngDgpgAgEIFcCWAbAJgUSwczgGcEBeBAHjgA80iISAVAPgG8EBtAaQTQDsEAazhQA9gDMEjALoAuBDmoBjDCixwKwsZMYAaBF2adpAbgQBfMCGCRYiVJlwFiFFmQTtuvAVolS5Csqq6poifnoGzBymFiZgYEqifPQI4gLkrgg0EHB8WCQO2HiERK7MzAAUcM5E8owAlGRGfCgYGHFgaRXsAIbyHABESgPS+gBG-QM9I-pKk9P6A2MjFvVmwMAIooI9UJ183Qh9nEMzCBMn06MIc5cDi8PSq+ubcABOb6JvAIRgQA)